# VB.NET Rotate graphics object around center

Tags: vb.net, graphics, rotatetransform

Apologies in advance if this is a stupid question.

I have a graphics object manipulating an image that I'm drawing over a panel with a background. What I want to do is have the image rotate around its center.
Here's the code I have the to the moment:

Global declarations:

```
Dim myBitmap As New Bitmap("C:\Users\restofthefilepath")  
Dim g As Graphics
```

Form1_Load:

```
g = Panel1.CreateGraphics
```

Timer1_tick (set to 1s intervals):

```
Panel1.Refresh()
g.DrawImage(myBitmap, -60, 110)
g.RenderingOrigin = New Point(160, 68)
g.RotateTransform(10)
```

And I get this: Left is after the first tick, Right is after the second tick.
[image]

(placeholder graphics)

As you can see I'm setting RenderingOrigin (as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13579984/4138037)): , but the rotation is still around 0,0. I've tried implementing RotateTransform(10, 160, 68) (with the centre of rotation specified) as [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform(v=vs.110).aspx) says should be possible, but I get a build error "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'RotateTransform' accepts this number of arguments".

Where am I going wrong, and how do I get the image to rotate around its center?

Comment: Regarding the build error, it is because you are using Windows Forms technology and that documentation is for System.Windows.Media (typically used with WPF).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Apart from rebuilding the project using WPF would you have any advice how I might resolve the build error?

Comment: Umm... aren't you meant to change the origin and do the rotation *before* you draw your image?

Comment: @AndrewMorton For proper use sure, but it shouldn't make any difference here. I've tried changing the order, and it makes no difference. g is still rotated between ticks, so when the next draw is called it draws rotated. The reason I did it this way is so the first drawing is unrotated (to test translation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started a new VB.NET Windows Forms project. I added a Panel of 200px x 200px and a Button to pause the animation as desired. I gave Panel1 a background image:

[image]

Made an image a little like yours:

[image]

and used the following code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim wiggle As Bitmap
    Dim tim As Timer

    Sub MoveWiggle(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Static rot As Integer = 0
        Panel1.Refresh()

        Using g = Panel1.CreateGraphics()
            Using fnt As New Font("Consolas", 12), brsh As New SolidBrush(Color.Red)
                ' the text will not be rotated or translated
                g.DrawString($"{rot}°", fnt, brsh, New Point(10, 10))
            End Using
            ' the image will be rotated and translated
            g.TranslateTransform(100, 100)
            g.RotateTransform(CSng(rot))
            g.DrawImage(wiggle, -80, 0)
        End Using

        rot = (rot + 10) Mod 360

    End Sub

    Private Sub bnPause_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnPause.Click
        Static isPaused As Boolean = False
        If isPaused Then
            tim.Start()
            bnPause.Text = "Pause"
        Else
            tim.Stop()
            bnPause.Text = "Start"
        End If

        isPaused = Not isPaused

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        wiggle = New Bitmap("C:\temp\path3494.png")
        wiggle.SetResolution(96, 96) ' my image had a strange resolution
        tim = New Timer With {.Interval = 50}
        AddHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf MoveWiggle
        tim.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing
        RemoveHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf MoveWiggle
        tim.Dispose()
        wiggle.Dispose()

    End Sub

End Class
```

and achieved this:

[image]

Note 1: It is important to set the transformations in the correct order.

Note 2: I called `.Dispose()` on the disposable resources in the `MyBase.Closing` event. This makes sure that memory is left clean and nothing leaks.

There are undoubtedly better ways to create animations, but at your desired one frame per second this achieves the effect you're after.